# How could I get those values exactly

Tags: json, format, spreadsheet

If I've got this result from Chrome console log ,how could I get those values exactly?
How could I get the value after first ":"?
(sometimes there's ":" in url value,can I filter this??)

["name: item1", " url: http://www.flickr.com/photos/nemoorange/5013039951/", " title: website", " photo: http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039951_3a47ccd509.jpg", " alt: Stanley", " p:  is a small proof of concept JavaScript library for zooming in on DOM elements or points in a document. It uses CSS3 transitions and 2D transforms (scaling", " translation", " transform origin) on the  element to achieve animated magnification
"]

Can it transform to JSON format of Array?
{"name":"item1",.....etc.}

thank you for your time ^^

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression to split each of the array elements at the first occurrence of each ":" will do the trick so long as none of the keys have a colon in them as the url value does.

This will iterates through the existing ill-formed array, split it with the regex and assign key-value pairs to the new object.

```
var newObject = {}

var myRegEx = new RegExp("(?<!:.*):");

foreach(var key in myArray){

    var tempArray = myArray[key].split(myRegEx);

    newObject[tempArray[0]] = tempArray[1];

}
```

Note: the .split() function automatically creates array elements "tempArray[0]" and "tempArray[1](http://www.jsonexample.com)" for *before and *after the split, respectively.

Use [jsonexample.com](http://www.jsonexample.com) for reference on other ways to form JSON objects

Cheers!